# facing issue with GWT designer mode

Tags: eclipse, gwt

I'm working with Eclipse Helios 3.6 (32-bit). I installed the GWT plug-in and created a new Web application. In the Client folder I was trying to open a file with GWT designer, but unfortunately I was getting an error:

> Internal Error encountered unexpected internal error. This could be caused by a bug or by a misconfiguration issue, conflict, partial update, etc.
>   `java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file`

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file   
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:620)  
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:299)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)  
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.tdt.HostedModeSupport.loadImpl
        (HostedModeSupport.java:110)  
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.tdt.HostedModeSupport.<init>
        (HostedModeSupport.java:83)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.hosted.tdt.HostedModeSupportFactory.create
        (HostedModeSupportFactory.java:32)
    at com.google.gdt.eclipse.designer.model.widgets.support.GwtState.getHostedModeSupport
        (GwtState... (missing part here)
    ...org.eclipse.wb.internal.core.editor.errors.ExceptionComposite$3.widgetSelected
        (ExceptionComposite.java:129)
```

--- etc

I have JavaCompiler in project properties 1.6 and from preferences->java->installed JDK/JRE using 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the specifics but most likely you are trying to run the designer with JDK 1.5. That is the cause of that error. I would recheck everything.

Also off the top of my head I would verify 32 bit versus 64 bit java sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Generally when anything is wrong in JavaCompiler Project properties it will throw error of major/minor version 51.0 . So here most probably by checking the java version installed in the system and the version through which you are working are differnet. Make both of them compatible and the error will be solved.